# Problem installing rpm using macports

Tags: macports

I am trying to install the rpm package using MacPorts, but this is what I get:

```
~ wdb$ sudo port install rpm
--->  Computing dependencies for rpm
Error: org.macports.activate for port rpm returned: error renaming 
"/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_rpm/rpm/work/destroot/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/rpm"
 to 
"/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_rpm/rpm/work/destroot/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/rpm": no such file or directory

Please see the log file for port rpm for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_rpm/rpm/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port rpm failed
~ wdb$
```

What is the exact problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a sanity check.  Did you assure that your ports install has been updated with `port selfupdate`etc?

Comment: @ephsmith yes, I did.

Comment: I would ask on the macports development list - given the python2.5 and perl5.8 dependencies I would guess this is an old port and needs to be redone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the rpm port. I have [filed bug report 35048](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35048) for you. I've also listed a workaround there and described how the maintainer of the port can fix it so the workaround is no longer needed.

The workaround is to install from source:

```
sudo port -f uninstall rpm
sudo port clean rpm
sudo port -s install rpm
```

Comment: The bug is marked as fixed, but what do I need to do to get that version on my system?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe run `sudo port selfupdate` to get the latest port metadata and then do the port install